# Rails redirect to www subdomain on https protocol

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From my understanding, at least with my domain host, there is no way to do a empty subdomain redirect to 'www' when the https protocol is used.

What is the best practice way of doing this in the application?

At the moment I have a before_filter in my ApplicationController with the following:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_subdomain

def redirect_to_subdomain
    (redirect_to '//www.domain.com' + request.path) if 'www.domain.com' != request.host
end
```

This seems to work when http protocol is used, but ignores with https. Not sure why that is though.

Comment: Not the problem, but why would you use a ternary there? You don't care about the else value, but the ternary makes you supply one, so you gave it `false`. Just use an if.

Comment: Oops. I was reducing code down from my production code for use in this example. You are right, the proper line would be (redirect_to '//www.domain.com' + request.path) if 'www.domain.com' != request.host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with [Rack Canonical Host](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host) middleware instead.